# Is it possible to update an object using spread operator, not creating new one?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3
};

Object.assing(object1, {b: 5});
```

This will make:

```
object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 5
}
```

The question is can this be achieved by spread operator ...
Which will return new Object instead of updating object1

```
var object2 = {...object1, b: 5}
```

Same as:

```
var object2 = Object.assign{{}, object1, {b: 5}}
```

Here

```
object2 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 5
}
```

but

```
object1 {
  a: 1,
  b: 3
};
```

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Comment: Since "object spread" can only be used inside an object literal you are always going to be creating a new object.

Comment: @FelixKling accepted, its not an operator, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `{...object1, b: 5}` you're creating a new object using object *literal notation*, which is used to [initialize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) a new object in memory.

So, when you do:

```
var object2 = {...object1, b: 5}
```

It's more or less the same as doing:

```
var object2 = {a: 1, b: 3, b: 5} // -> {a: 1, b: 5} -> creating a new object
```

So, the thing which is creating the new object here isn't the spread syntax (`...`), but rather the object literal (`{}`).

Thus, unless you're willing to reassign `object1` to the new object reference, you won't be able to modify `object1` in-place solely using the spread syntax.

Comment: ya i got it Thanks!, that is question, is it possible or not, and the answer it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the spread right side to object1

```js
var object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 3
};

object1 = { ...object1,b: 5};
console.log(object1);
```

Comment: pretty much like object1 = object2, which changes the reference of object1, i know this, but i am wondering without changing the reference

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh Since this is the trivial and obvious solution, can you clarify why you don't like it? Or what your actual goal is here?

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh goal of spread operator is to change the reference of object could you please let us know what are purpose for this.

Comment: The goal is just to edit a bigger object with some properties as Object.assign with first parameter as object to edit. In some scenarios, may be let's say where view will update based on the object's some properties, or some kind of an event for change of  the object reference, will trigger even when we don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator requires you to create a new object. `Object.assign` however, takes as first parameter the object to edit. It is usually used with an empty object, but you can use it as follow.

```js
const object1 = { b: 5 }
Object.assign(object1, { a: 1 })

console.log(object1) // { b:5, a: 1}
```

Comment: This is given is question itself right? Thanks the answer is in ur explanation.